# NUnit test generator

Tags: testing, nunit, generator

What good (free) generator can be recommended for NUnit tests?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon - I should have been more peciseley...
I'm looking for a stub generater.

Example:
1. got a class,
2. generate some a testcase stub with corresponding name
3. generate test methods stubs for public methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just downloaded and installed Novel's [NUnitGenAddIn](http://forge.novell.com/modules/xfmod/project/?nunitgenaddin).  It's kind of old-ish (seems to have been last updated in 2006), but once I tweaked the NUnitGenAddIn.AddIn file (change the Assembly path and update the Visual Studio version number to 9.0), it does exactly what I wanted: right-click generation of reasonable unit-test stubs from within Visual Studio 2008.  Dunno if that works for what you want, but definitely free (GNU Lesser GPL).

Answer (score 11):

You're going to have to say exactly what you want the generator to do. Personally I've always found automated generators to be more hassle than they're worth - my fingers work just as well :)

On the other hand, you might want to look at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) which works in conjunction with [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to explore your code and generate tests in an intelligent way. Pex is able to generate tests in different flavours, including NUnit.

Comment: NUnit support is now out of the box for Pex.

Answer (score 3):

Test generators are good at giving you high code coverage. Unfortunately high code coverage doesn't always mean good tests have been generated. I tend to write them out by hand myself.

Answer (score 1):

Dont do it. Tests with value are generated first, by a human (ideally a pair thereof) with their thinking caps on, not their brain in neutral. (That is if you're referring to generating a test per method, or anything else that's not based on some deep insight a la Pex as Jon Skeet said)

Answer (score 0):

If you use resharper you can right-click on a class or method and generate a test class plus one or more test methods (Sorry this was wrong it is part of vs2010)